# Oracle - ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00917

```
INSERT INTO contact(id, org_name, street_address1, street_address2,  
   city, state, postal_code, country_code, last_name, first_name,
   person_title, phone_country_code, phone_area-code, phone_number, email, created_time)
VALUES(20, 'cognizant', 'chennai', 'ckc',
   'tamilnadu', '092345', '0934', 'Edwin', 'Michael',
   'MR', 09, 10, '0924242', 'edwin@seic.com', 09824);
```

When I am trying to execute the code above, I'm getting the error below:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: I edited your question's formatting to break up the fields by line. This should make it clearer to see that you're missing a field.

Answer (score 3):

- i think the column name `phone_area-code` is
  `phone_area_code`(a`hyphen` can not be used for a column name)
- the last value should be quoted as `'09824'` which's non-integer as having a leading zero
- the values list has `15` items, while column names list has `16`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have tried the query by updating it,

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the value for the `state`. If you don't have a value for it, you must pass it as empty string `''` or `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO contact(id, org_name, street_address1, street_address2,  
   city, state, postal_code, country_code, last_name, first_name,
   person_title, phone_country_code, phone_area-code, phone_number, email, created_time)
VALUES(20, 'cognizant', 'chennai', 'ckc',
   'tamilnadu', '', '092345', '0934', 'Edwin', 'Michael',
   'MR', 09, 10, '0924242', 'edwin@seic.com', 09824);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column count 16 but your data that you inserted only 15. You missing one value there, just put single quote '', for the missing value or the value that you dont want to input anything.